# Google Datastore Performance

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google Datastore in a project that has only one Table (Type) with almost 1 million entities (entries) and keep growing.

My application scope is growing and I have to add more and more properties in this Table.

My question is: If I keep adding more and more properties in this table, Is It going to decrease query performance? Is It better to add those new properties in others Table?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer: you shouldn't have to worry about the query performance, queries use indexes and are typically not affected by the number of entities being indexed.

There are, however, a few corner cases with some impact on datastore performance you should be aware of, depending on your app's particular use of the datastore, listed in the [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices) article.